# How to copy just the first match when using cp in BASH with multiple possible matches?

Tags: bash, copy

I have a directory of PNG files names according to the description of the contents, e.g.:

```
images/blueberry.png
images/blueberry_garden.png
images/blueberry_painting.png
images/carrot_garden.png
```

I also have a list of keywords, e.g.:

```
blueberry
garden
```

I need to copy just one file from `images/` into `output/` so that there is one image named exactly like the keywords, e.g.:

```
images/blueberry.png → output/blueberry.png
images/blueberry_garden.png → output/garden.png
```

It does not matter which one of the matching files is copied from `image/`, so long as it contains the keyword.

In a BASH script, I have this line, to find a file with the word "garden" and copy it to `output/garden.png`:

```
cp images/*garden* output/garden.png
```

If it finds only one file matching that, it copies fine. When it finds more than one match, however, it doesn't copy anything.

How can I copy the files such that just one of the possible matches is selected to be copied?

Comment: The problem isn't that it doesn't copy anything. In fact it copies everything fine, it just copies it all to the exact same filename.

Comment: @BroSlow: Actually, I think `cp` reports an error if there are multiple source files and the target is not a _directory_.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks, didn't know about the special case. Suppose it makes sense, but still a bit surprised it's hardcoded to assume it's a directory in one case and either a directory or a file in another.

Comment: I found on both Linux and OS X, `cp *keyword* keyword.png` does not copy anything. Maybe different systems will work differently.

Comment: @BroSlow: I guess the logic is: `cp` is designed to create a copy of _each_ input file, so if you want to copy _more than 1_ file, the only way to do this sensibly is to specify a target _directory_ (copying all input files to a single output file to let the last one 'win' is pointless; the alternative, to concatenate all input files, is not what `cp` does).

Comment: @Village: What `cp *keyword* keyword.png` does **depends entirely on what `*keyword*` expands to**, i.e. what files happen to match: (a) If _none_ match, `cp` will fail (either complaining that no such file exists or complaining about invalid syntax, if `shopt -s nullglob` is in effect). (b) If *1* file matches, the command will succeed (assuming no other problems). (c) If _more than 1_ file matches, `cp` will fail again, because it will refuse to copy multiple input files to a single output _file_ (as opposed to a directory). Applies to both OS X and Linux, I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the matching filenames in an array, and then copy the first element of the array.

```
files=(images/*garden*)
cp "${files[0]}" output/garden.png
```

Comment: On MacBook zsh, the array is 1-based. files[0] is empty!

Comment: OK, but the question is about bash, not zsh.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there is a way to force [cp](/questions/tagged/cp) to copy only some number of times, but you can put the following function in a sourced file, e.g. `~/.bashrc`

```
cpone() {
  [[ "${!#}" =~ '/'$ ]] && last="${!#}" || last="${!#}/"
  cp "$1" "$last${1##*_}"
}
```

Then you would run it like

```
> ls images output
images:
blueberry_garden.png  blueberry_painting.png  blueberry.png  carrot_garden.png

output:

>  cpone images/*garden* output    
> ls output
garden.png
> cpone images/*blueberry* output 
cp: overwrite ‘output/garden.png’?
```

This is assuming keyword is anything after the last `_` or just the file if `_` doesn't exist.